# Upload a DOCX file in a SharePoint Library using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I Am trying to upload a word file in a SharePoint document library in SharePoint 2013 environment.
File is uploaded successfully every time but it is corrupted.

```
string siteurl = "http://myurl/sandbox/training";
        string documentlibrary = "Shared Documents"; //Document library where file needs to be uploaded

        string filePath = @"C:\temp\myfile.docx";

        byte[] binary = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string result = string.Empty;
        //Url to upload file
        string resourceUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api",siteurl);

        RestClient RC = new RestClient(resourceUrl);
        NetworkCredential NCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        RC.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(NCredential);

        Console.WriteLine("Creating Rest Request");
        RestRequest Request = new RestRequest("contextinfo?$select=FormDigestValue", Method.POST);
        Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        Request.AddHeader("Body", "");

        string ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
        int StartPos = ReturnedStr.IndexOf("FormDigestValue") + 18;
        int length = ReturnedStr.IndexOf(@""",", StartPos) - StartPos;
        string FormDigestValue = ReturnedStr.Substring(StartPos, length);

        Console.WriteLine("Uploading file Site……");

        resourceUrl = string.Format("/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/Files/add(url='{1}',overwrite=true)", documentlibrary ,fname);
        Request = new RestRequest(resourceUrl, Method.POST);
        //Request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        Request.AddBody(Convert.ToBase64String(binary));
        //Request.AddParameter("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", Convert.ToBase64String(binary), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        //Request.AddFileBytes("someName", binary, fname, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        //Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
        Request.AddHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);
        ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
```

**Update**: This worked

```
 resourceUrl = string.Format("/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{0}')/Files/add(url='{1}',overwrite=true)", documentlibrary ,"test.docx");
        Request = new RestRequest(resourceUrl, Method.POST);
        Request.AddParameter("application/json", binary, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        Request.AddHeader("X-RequestDigest", FormDigestValue);

        ReturnedStr = RC.Execute(Request).Content;
```